# Cannot open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock permission denied--even using sudo

Tags: dpkg

I recently installed a fresh version of Ubuntu LTS 12.04.  I had been using LTS 10.4 and saved my package.list and was planning on using

```
$> sudo dpkg --set-selections < package.list && apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

to install the same packages in the new version

However, the computer fails to run with the error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)  
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

The simple answers to this would be am I root or a member of sudo?

```
  $> whoami

  surfer

   $> groups

surfer adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

So much for the easy answer.

Per the similar post 
[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock/15469#15469)
The recommended solution is

```
$> sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Upon executing that command, my screen goes blank, the keyboard becomes unresponsive, and my only option is to press the power button and reboot... (I would have thought this was a malicious suggestion, but many others seemed to have liked it.)

I've tried listing any programs that may be using `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`

```
$> sudo lsof 

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/surfer/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Note, there are no programs listed.

Similarly, no luck with

```
$> ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
```

Nothing listed.

BTW, I can run apt-get from the command line.

```
$> sudo apt-get update
```

runs as expected and updates my package lists...

@izx: 
After attempting your suggestion, I could not run

```
$> sudo dpkg --set-selections < package.list && apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

It failed with the same error.  I tried this

**a)** immediately following the rm command in the F1 terminal
**b)** executing the rm command and returning to X with Ctrl+Alt+F7
**c)** executing the rm command and rebooting

Of interest only option **c)** yielded a different (but similar error message) which was

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

Although I cannot kill the processes using `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` with `fuser`, I did get the following output for processes that are linked to it.

```
$> fuser -cv /var/lib/dpkg/lock  
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND  
/var/lib/dpkg/lock:  root     kernel mount (root)/var  
                     surfer     1641 ....m (surfer)gnome-settings-  
                     surfer     1656 ....m (surfer)compiz  
                     surfer     1679 ....m (surfer)nm-applet  
                     surfer     1688 ....m (surfer)nautilus  
                     surfer     1731 ....m (surfer)gtk-window-deco  
                     surfer     1733 ....m (surfer)unity-panel-ser  
                     surfer     1831 ....m (surfer)gnome-terminal  
                     surfer     1899 f.... (surfer)unity-applicati  
                     surfer     2029 F...m (surfer)update-notifier
```

So I tried killing each process from the F1 terminal, and removed the lock file. No problem.   The result was

```
$> fuser -cv /var/lib/dpkg/lock  
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND  
/var/lib/dpkg/lock:  root     kernel mount (root)/var  

$> ls /var/lib/dpkg/lock  
ls: cannot access /var/lib/dpkg/lock: No such file or directory
```

file and links seem to be gone, but upon executing the `dpkg` command, I get the same error...and the lock file is back.

I'm really rather puzzled, and would welcome any help.

Comment: If you think this below solution solved your problem , do Consider marking it as answer by Ticking the RIGHT tick mark Left to it. Thank You.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your very First step should have been

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < package.list && sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

The following error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
```

would have **never** occurred , Even `second time` you used the same code, and got same error.

Try the right command by adding **sudo** as per above , and post your findings.

**NOTE** : The use of **&&** enables you to execute multiple commands on same line , in the usual sense **&&** only executes the **second** command if the **first** command returns a value reporting **success** . Therefore ,**sudo** here needs to be specified in **second** command .

Comment: Thank you tijybba and Eliah.  That was the missing element. Works fine now.  Changed to Solved.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then retry.

This problem can also arise if there are other installations running.

Comment: As [explained in an earlier answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/163172/22949), this problem is caused by one of the `apt-get` commands that needed to be run as `root`, not being run as `root`. Configuring all half-installed packages (`sudo dpkg --configure -a`) does not address that.

Comment: `Unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or diretory`

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If u still get lock error try this command It will give the process detail

```
ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
```

Then kill the process using process ID then execute the update command

And also u can delete this file your problem will solve

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock 

sudo dpkg --set-selections < package.list && sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, this worked for me:

> This error indicates that you (or some program/script) changed the
> permissions of the file /var/lib/dpkg/status. Please change them back
> via: "sudo chmod 644 /var/lib/dpkg/status" in order to fix the issue.

I ended up opening terminal:

```
sudo nautilus
```

navigating to the folders/files, and changing permissions to

> ME - FOLDER:FULL ACCESS / FILES: READ WRITE
>
> ROOT - FOLDER: FULL ACCESS / FILES: READ ONLY

The problem came when my permissions got screwed when trying to fix a kernel issue I had with an Nvidia driver... but that's another story..

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

In rare times, you can get this problem without other `dpkg` process locks by user with sudo privilege.

I encountered this problem for unknown reasons that I got this folder lost.

I tried all the other solutions suggested here, but none worked. My simple way was to copy a `/var/lib/dpkg` folder from another server with the same version Ubuntu.

Hope it helps if someone else had the same thing happen to them.